# Add/Remove 1000 separator (Comma) From Integer Field In ArcGIS Collector?

Tags: arcgis-online, fields-attributes, arcgis-collector

I have a team of inspectors using ArcGIS collector to collect and edit data.  When I set up the web map in AGOL I obviously wasn't thinking clearly and checked some fields to Use 1000 Separator (Years, ID numbers) and others I left unchecked (Lengths, $ amounts).  I inverted the selection I needed.  I had the team download the map and inspectors are using it in the field.  I corrected the 1000 separator mistake in AGOL, but when I sync in collector it still will not correct the problem.  This may sound a bit OCD, but the 1000 separators are actually causing a bit of disturbance in the way we collect data.

Does anybody know a way to correct this without downloading the map over again?

Comment: I am fairly confident the answer to this one is going to be a no.  This formatting is controlled at the Web Map level under the popup configuration settings and you cannot override this in the Collector app.  If you delete and install the Collector app again does that fix it? Or simply logging out and in again?

Comment: You will have to download the map again to pick up the spec change in the web map. So the users would sync changes, delete the map, pull to refresh to grab the spec change, download map.